# Erlang - List-index permutations without repeating the same indexes

Tags: algorithm, erlang

I have an Erlang list: `[0, 4, 3, 0]`. I'm trying to find all combinations without repeating the same permutation(s) ― based on the list indexes.

For instance, the final result I'm looking for is: `[{0,4}, {0,3}, {0,0}, {4,3}, {4,0}, {3,0}]`.

...or if I would put the list combinations in a matrix, with `i` denoting the indexes of the list, this would be the result:

```
  {i[0], i[1]}, {i[0], i[2]}, {i[0], i[3]}
  {i[1], i[0]}, {i[1], i[2]}, {i[1], i[3]}
  {i[2], i[0]}, {i[2], i[1]}, {i[2], i[3]}
  {i[3], i[0]}, {i[3], i[1]}, {i[3], i[2]}
```

I'm trying with lists comprehensions, but no luck so far:

```
gorre@uplink:~/erlang$ erl
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V9.1  (abort with ^G)
1> L = [0, 4, 3, 0].
[0,4,3,0]
2> [{X, Y} || X <- L, Y <- L, X < Y].                                  
[{0,4},{0,3},{3,4},{0,4},{0,3}]
3> [{X, Y} || X <- L, Y <- L, X > Y].
[{4,0},{4,3},{4,0},{3,0},{3,0}]
4> [{X, Y} || X <- L, Y <- L].       
[{0,0}, {0,4}, {0,3}, {0,0},
 {4,0}, {4,4}, {4,3}, {4,0},
 {3,0}, {3,4}, {3,3}, {3,0},
 {0,0}, {0,4}, {0,3}, {0,0}]
5>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with recursion. Here's the algorithm of the code below: we start with the list. On each call, we combine the head of the list with each element of the tail. Then, we recurse with the tail of the list.

```
combinations([]) -> [];
combinations([Head | Tail]) -> [{Head, X} || X <- Tail] ++ combinations(Tail).
```

```
1> a:combinations([0, 4, 3, 0]).
[{0,4},{0,3},{0,0},{4,3},{4,0},{3,0}]
```